# Override Shipping Rates at checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, after-plugin

I am simply looking to get the shipping rates from the current quote and override them via a plugin/interceptor but have no idea where I'm going wrong here:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MethodPlugin
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function beforeSetPrice($subject, $price)
    {
        $this->_logger->debug("Current price is " . $price);

        return $price;
    }

    public function afterSetPrice($subject, $price)
    {
        $price = 3.33;
        $this->_logger->debug("New price is " . $price);

        return $price;
    }
}
```

My thinking was that the `beforeSetPrice()` method would log the current price (which it does) and the `afterSetPrice()` method would log the new price (which it does) AND update the price shown in the shipping rates on checkout (which it doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution worked for me:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Model\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

class MethodPlugin
{

    public function afterSetPrice($subject)
    {
        $new_price = "2.00";

        $subject->setData("price", $new_price);

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did'nt work for me , I am using Magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

To set shipping rates on checkout just add custom price in beforeSetPrice function. It will update the price.

**Note: if you have multiple shipping methods then it will update price for all shipping method.**

```
public function beforeSetPrice($subject, $price)
    {
        $this->_logger->debug("Current price is " . $price);
        $price = 3.33;
        return $price;
    }
```

Comment: You were on the right lines with this Poojan so thank you :) However I have edited my post with the solution I found to be more suitable to my purpose. Thanks again for your help though!